# Stack name is shown for EC2 instances instead of Name tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to spin out EC2 instances through AutoscallingGroup. Using AWS CDK java language.
I am setting the name tag and PropagateAtLaunch: 'true'. But still EC2 instances name are shown as stack name and not the name tag value.
Any help on this.

Comment: Do you have any of your configuration I.e. CloudFormation ?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams U mean Cloudformation template?

Comment: Yes please if you have it :)

Comment: asgASG4D014670:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MaxSize: "2"
      MinSize: "1"
      AutoScalingGroupName: iot-project-asg
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: asgLaunchConfig37FDE42B
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: IOT
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: IotApplicationInfraStack/asg

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I am able to solve it using priority.

```
Tag.add(this, ApplicationConstant.NAME_TAG, topology.getProject(), TagProps.builder().applyToLaunchedInstances(true).priority(300).build());
```